# Swift - can a function accept a throwing function that returns a tuple as a parameter?

Tags: swift, tuples

Is there a way in Swift to have a parameter accept a throwing function that returns a tuple as a parameter?

For example, I have this code where `sendNewInvitation` is a throwing function returns a tuple `(UserProfile, [GroupMembership])`.

I mean to pass this in as a parameter for `updateUserMemberships,` and the easiest way I can think of to do it is to set a separate variable as the result of `sendNewInvitation`, and then set each part of the tuple.

But I intend to have `updateUserMemberships` accept the results of several other functions, and I'm wondering if there is a way to do all of this in one line?

Current Code:

```
            do {
                let userAndMembership = try sendNewInvitation(user: user, group: group)
                try updateUserMemberships(user: userAndMembership.0, groupMemberships: userAndMembership.1)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
```

Ideally, I'm wondering if there's a way to do something like this
(within the do block):
`try updateUserMemberships(tuple: try sendNewInvitation)`
(And I could redeclare the function to accept the parameters either as separate parameters or as a tuple of this type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem calling a throwing function inside the call to another function, if the first function throws the `catch` clause will be entered and the second function never gets called. You can simply redefine the function to take a tuple instead

```
func updateUserMemberships(userInfo: (UserProfile, [GroupMembership])) throws {
    ...
}
```

And call the other function inside the call to `updateUserMemberships

```
do {
    try updateUserMemberships(userInfo: try sendNewInvitation(user: user, group: group))
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}
```

You can create a type alias for your tuple if it helps improve readability

```
typealias UserInfo = (UserProfile, [GroupMembership])

func sendNewInvitation(user: String, group: String) throws -> UserInfo {
    ...
}

func updateUserMemberships(userInfo: UserInfo) throws {}
```

But if this is a type you are going to use in many places then I suggest you wrap it in a struct instead

```
struct UserInfo {
    var userProfile: UserProfile
    var groupMembership: [GroupMembership])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the result of a throwing function as a parameter to another function, `try` is only needed once for the entire expression. In the following example, if `foo()` throws then `bar()` is not called and execution goes to the `catch` block:

```
func foo(n: Int) throws -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    if n == 0 {
        throw NSError(domain: "domain", code: 13, userInfo: nil)
    }
    return (1, 2, 3)
}

func bar(tuple: (Int, Int, Int)) {
    print(tuple)
}

do {
    try bar(tuple: foo(n: 0))
    print("success")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`rethrows` to the rescue!

```
func sendNewInvitation(...) throws -> (UserProfile, [GroupMembership])  {
    ...
}

func updateUserMemebership(yourFunction: (...) throws -> (UserProfile, [GroupMembership])) rethrows {
    try yourFunction(...)
}


try updateUserMemebership(yourFunction: sendNewInvitation(...))
```

Note: this example is here just to illustrate the usage of `rethrows`. There are likely better ways to structure your code.